# Running and Debugging the Protractor Cucumber tests in Intellij IDEA

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, protractor, cucumber

I am trying to Run and Debug Protractor cucumber tests. But I couldn't. Please help me out and suggest what I am missing here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please update question with feature file content.

Comment: Please share the code sample. Error can happen i.e. in this case: https://github.com/kozhevnikov/cucumber-pretty/issues/10